# Windows 10 select default login option

Tags: windows, windows-10, login, pin

I have created a PIN to make logging in on my laptop a bit faster. Now the problem is, that, by default, my laptop asks me for my password. This is somewhat annoying, since it takes 2 clicks to switch to the pin. I have to do this every first time i unlock my pc. When it was in locked mode, it remembers the last selected login option. But after a boot this somehow is forgotten again.

(Maybe important: I disabled the required authentification on boot time, so that a pwd/pin is only required after it was locked)

Can i set the "default login option" somewhere?

Comment: You are not alone: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-security/set-pin-as-default-sign-in-option/d0aac9c1-88cf-44c4-a1b2-2ddc519d1881?page=3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had the same problem since installing Win 10 and the issue has persisted across multiple Insider builds. As far as I can tell from my research, this is either a bug or is the expected behavior. The only good reference I have on this is from Microsoft Community:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-security/set-pin-as-default-sign-in-option/d0aac9c1-88cf-44c4-a1b2-2ddc519d1881

It's three mostly-useless pages, but as per the latest comments from January, others seem to be experiencing the same behavior and there is no known way to change it.

Comment: Okay well seems like I have to live with it. Thanks for the clarification

Comment: possible duplicate and fix / workaround in: https://superuser.com/questions/1187522/windows-10-fingerprint-login-changes-default-login-method-back-to-password

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason is another credential provider was added to your windows.

Tools & Steps to check the credential providers:

1. Download Windows sysinternals: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/
2. Launch autoruns.exe to check the stuffs that are loaded when windows starts
3. Switch to Winlogon tab, check if there are additional credential providers

   [Examples: the credential provider on my windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gcx9j.jpg)
4. ***!!!CAUTION!!! POSSIBLE DAMAGE TO YOUR WINDOWS***

   Find out which are the alien credential providers

   ***BE VERY CAREFUL!!!*** Uncheck the aliens (***CAUTION!!! DO THIS STEP AT YOUR OWN RISKS***)

   Reboot

For myself, I am SURE that "PanV2 SSO" in the above example is a VPN Software from GlobalProtect which is used to connect to my workplace; and I am SURE disabling this item will NOT do harm to my windows.

Again, if you find an alien credential provider, ***MAKE A RESTORE POINT in windows BEFORE YOU UNCHECK IT in autoruns!***