# How do I sign in with a password instead of a pin?

Tags: windows-10, passwords, pin

I'm using Windows 10. It defaults to a PIN. I want it to default to a password instead. I did this about 2 years ago so I know it can be done but now I can't figure out how I changed it. Does anyone know? All searched I do only talk about how to change to a PIN.

Comment: I use the PIN as password (can be as complicated as you want) as it's somewhat easier to remember than my long and random Microsoft account's password which I need my password manager for.

Comment: Question can it be that there already exists an answer?: https://superuser.com/questions/1187522/windows-10-fingerprint-login-changes-default-login-method-back-to-password   this one looks like it is about changing your DEFAULT method

Answer (score 15):

Click on Sign In Options. There is a set of icons below the sign in options. The middle icon is for Password.  Click on that and the entry box changes to Password. Default is PIN but it is easily changed and I do this myself.

The screen shot below is from my own ThinkPad which has PIN, Password and Fingerprint Reader. Of course, different machines have different setups and might show a different screen. In any event, if there is more than one sign-in method, you can always click on Sign In Options.

[image]

Comment: Would also be useful if you could demonstrate how can you change the default from PIN to password.

Comment: If you have a PIN , then the default is PIN. I have never changed this because I have Fingerprint, PIN and Password and just select what I need. @Moab: I logged off but then SnagIt was not there. Your idea is a good one and I am going to try again.

Comment: I added a photo. Had to use my iPhone at the login screen

Comment: This is actually the only answer that answers the author's question.  **If anyone is wondering, the default "Sign-in Option" is simply the option that was last used, so changing the default "Sign-in Option" is as simple as picking the password option.**  [How To Change The Default Sign In Option In Windows 10](https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/change-default-sign-in-option-windows-10/).  "This change is permanent unless you change it back. To change it back, simply lock the screen again, and click Sign in options. Select the default sign in option again, and it will be reset."

Comment: That may depend on the system and use. My system defaults to PIN even though I often use password. So it will not always be Last Option - certainly not for me.

Comment: The Picture above was edited and while come from some machines, is not at all like my machine, proving only that different OS setups will have login setups (which we know to be true)

Comment: If a password and pin are both set, then your original screenshot is the correct list of options (minus the fingerprint).  New screenshot doesn't even have a password set.  It's pin or 2FA (Smart Card) and isn't even applicable to the author.  The edit shouldn't have been approved.

Comment: The words of my answer are correct and "Sign-in Options" is always available if there is more than one method, so that is all one needs to do.

Answer (score 8):

On newer versions of Windows 10, you can't change "Sign-in options" to use password. The only option you have is *"I forgot my PIN"*:

[image: I forgot my PIN]

If you connect your Microsoft Account without adding a PIN, you have *"Sign in"* option:

[image: Sign in without a PIN]

But that *"Sign in"* requires your PC to be connected to Internet. You can't log in to your Microsoft Account offline. If you enabled two-factor authentication, then you also have to receive SMS code. Yes, you have to receive SMS code every time you log in to your Windows account.

Actually it is **still possible to log in with just a password instead of a PIN**, but you need to change settings first. Go to *Settings -> Accounts -> Sign-in options*. Disable *"Require Windows Hello sign-in for Microsoft accounts"* option:

[image]

This option may be grayed out, if you didn't set up a PIN. Therefore you have to create a PIN before changing this option. After creating a PIN, close the *Settings* and open them again. After that you can disable *"Require Windows Hello sign-in"* option.

After disabling this option, you can log in to Microsoft Account using a password:

[image]

If you want to make logging in by password the default sign-in option, then click *"Sign-in options"* again before typing a password. Once other sign-in options are hidden, logging in by password will be your default sign-in option.

Actually you can even delete a PIN now. Close *Settings* and open them again. There you will have *"Remove"* option for your Windows Hello PIN:

[image]

After removing the PIN, a password will the only option to log in to your Microsoft Account.

Comment: Turning off "Require Windows Hello sign-in" worked for me.  I could then choose to use a password on the login page. That took a few tries on first use, but it eventually synced with the online account and worked.  This is required to be able to use Remote Desktop from a different computer to this one!

Answer (score 2):

You can only set up a PIN if you've set up a password on your Windows 10 user account. Once you set up a PIN, you will have the option to either change or remove it and you don't have option to set default login method. To remove your PIN, follow these steps:

Click the Windows logo (Start button).

Click the gear icon (Settings).

Select Accounts.

On the left pane, choose Sign-in options.

Under PIN, press Remove.

Click Remove again.

Enter the user account password, and then click OK.

After doing the steps above, you can sign-out to your account to see if you will be able to log-in using the password.

Comment: Is your answer saying that the only way to access an account with a password is to remove the pin associated with the account?  The author is looking to keep both the password and the pin but by default have Windows request the password instead of the pin.

Answer (score 0):

The first step you need to do is go to Settings -> Accounts -> Sign-in options, and then Add a new password.

[image]

Once you have done that step, you can remove your PIN to use password to login instead of PIN. It requires you to set a password before switching or removing the PIN.

Comment: Based on the author's description their account already has a password,  It also appears the author wants to keep the pin to their account but change what is requested by default.  I suspect the last option used is going to be the default.

Answer (score -2):

You can do this by removing the PIN from Windows sign in options in settings. And if you are like me, and want to use a different password to login other than the email password, Just dont remove the PIN, instead change it and when it asks for new PIN, select the 'Include letters and numbers ' option . And now you can give a text password as PIN even without including numbers.