# Is there a Windows 10 shortcut for switching to use a password for signing in?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

If I add an additional sign-in method to my computer - e.g. fingerprint, PIN etc. - then entering a password is not the first method to show up when I turn it on. Is there a keyboard shortcut to allow me to enter in my password instead of another method, rather than using the mouse?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I sign in with a password instead of a pin?](https://superuser.com/questions/1526416/how-do-i-sign-in-with-a-password-instead-of-a-pin)

Comment: @RomeoNinov none of the answers in that question talk about a keyboard shortcut to change the login method, at the login screen.

Comment: @RomeoNinov - This does not answer my question. If there was a way to change the default log-in method to password instead of PIN, it would solve my XY problem, but none of the answers in the linked question seem to have a suggestion to achieve this.

Comment: @Lou - So you are saying that if you log into your account using a password, by clicking on the [icon](https://cloud.addictivetips.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/sigin-in-options.jpg), the next time you are asked to log into your account you are asked to use a pin instead of a password?  Just to confirm, you have disabled, "Require Windows Hello sign-in for Microsoft accounts"?  In my personal experience on my 21H1 VM, I have found doing those steps, actually did work to change the default authentication method.

Comment: You can change the default Windows 10 sign-in method through a registry fix: https://superuser.com/a/1187556/403203. And while it isn't a keyboard shortcut, you could do `Tab`, `Tab`, `Space`, `Tab`, `Tab`, `Space` to quickly switch to password instead of PIN without the need of a mouse. It can be quite fast once you do it a few times.