# Can't change Windows 11's PIN without access to Internet

Tags: pin, windows-hello, windows-11-v22h2

**tl;dr** *I am locked in Windows 11's lock screen with my PIN revoked (due to hardware change) and no Internet connection to setup an new one. Cannot bypass lock screen at all and do anything in Windows itself. Is there anything I can do, except for performing clean install?*

---

I have restored my system from an image to a different hardware. This caused my PIN to be locked with *Your PIN is no longer available* message and a *Setup new PIN* button. This functionality requires, however, an active Internet access and logging into Microsoft account.

The underlying Windows 11 (restored from image) does not have drivers for wireless or wired network cards installed<sup>1</sup>. I the effect, I am without any kind of Internet connection available.

Is there anything that I can do in this situation?

Most, if not all guides that I have found in the Internet are totally worthless for me, because they tell me to do something *in Windows itself* (like running command-line or accessing Settings) while I *cannot pass lock screen* and access Windows at all.

Things that I have tried so far:

1. The [*Recover Mode → Startup Repair*](https://www.technipages.com/windows-11-your-pin-is-no-longer-available/) if of no use; my Windows starts normally
2. [Uninstalling recent updates](https://www.technipages.com/windows-11-your-pin-is-no-longer-available/) brings no resolution because it is hardware change not update install that caused my system to revoke PIN number
3. [Cannot use password](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/reset-your-pin-when-you-aren-t-signed-in-to-windows-a386c519-3ab2-b873-1e9b-bb228a98b904#WindowsVersion=Windows_11) because there are no *Sign-in options* or *I forgot my PIN* buttons available
4. I don't want to [rollback my system to previous version](https://10scopes.com/fix-your-pin-is-no-longer-available-on-windows-11/)
5. I cannot [use Microsoft account to setup a new PIN](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Q7mhcYUaHQ) because my PC does not have Internet access.
6. Cannot [use Safe Mode](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/cant-change-windows-pin-without-internet-cant/b90d4673-3093-47a3-86b5-82c2135075d9), because in Windows 11 even Safe Mode requires valid PIN and entering Safe Mode ends with being locked as well
7. I don't need to [run System File Checker, Disk Check or DISM](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/cant-change-windows-pin-without-internet-cant/b90d4673-3093-47a3-86b5-82c2135075d9), because nothing wrong is with my computer. It's a brand new computer and a brand new disk that has system restored from image.
8. I cannot [remove my existing PIN](https://superuser.com/questions/1526416/how-do-i-sign-in-with-a-password-instead-of-a-pin/1607370#1607370) because this requires access to the Windows which I don't have.
9. [Removing *Ngc* folder](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/cant-log-in-without-pin-and-not-able-to-reset-it/97df30eb-b199-43bd-8b53-9947338cfbc7) using Repair Mode and console inside, which was supposedly reset / remove my PIN was not possible in my case as I don't have *Ngc* folder inside *C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\AppData\Local\Microsoft* path (the path itself is valid and exists, but it is empty)
10. [Typing `net user administrator /active:yes` in Repair Mode](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-11-home-sign-in-click-doesnt-show-sign-in/9abcd349-5c01-42e0-bd80-3fe9f27e8662) brings no solution. Command line confirms that change has been applied but after reboot there's no change and I am not able to login to the built-in administrator account
11. Resetting Windows with keeping files brings no resolution, as after this I bump again with *Your PIN is no longer available* message

Is there anything else that I can try or do? Anything else then performing clean install?

<sup>1</sup><sub>The weirdest part of this story is that Windows (after restoring it from an image) was able to install the least important audio card driver, but wasn't able to install the most crucial: graphic card or network adapter's drivers.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can establish an Internet connection over USB, either by using an USB-to-Ethernet adapter, or by using an Android phone as follows:

1. Plug your Android's phone to PC's USB port.
2. Enable USB tethering
3. Wait.

That's all. After about 5-10 minutes Windows silently installs all the missing drivers, including graphic card and network.