# How can I restore only one registry key from registry back up I had?

Tags: windows, backup, windows-registry, windows-11

I want to restore only one key from registy back up I had in here:

```
%systemroot\System32\config\RegBack
```

How can I do this?

I just changed some permissions on [this registry](https://superuser.com/a/1265040/1728892) and my PC is not working correctly.
I have registry backup but I don't know how can I restore only one key. or even restore all of it.

Comment: If System Restore is enabled, the simplest would be to rollback to before the changes were made.

Answer (score 2):

1. Attach the registry hive file using `reg load` (e.g. under HKLM\Foo).

   If you want to use the RegEdit GUI, this is under "File → Load".
2. Use `reg save` to make a new backup file of only the subkey you want. (If you only want the data and don't need to preserve original permissions, you can use `reg export` to generate the text-based .reg file.)
3. Use `reg unload` to detach the original full backup.
4. Use `reg restore` (or `reg import`) to restore the real subkey from the new backup.